# "no working init" at installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04, init

I have a problem when I try to install Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop.

I have a Dell Inspiron 5558. The pendrive is noname, but usable, I installed another OS with it already (as a try after I couldn't Ubuntu), so now there is Deepin OS on the laptop.

In advance I write some info what would be the first thought for everyone:

1. I tried both UEFI and Legacy
2. I tried downloading the ISO again, from
   all mirrors
3. Checksum is correct
4. Secure boot, fast startup all turned off
5. In boot sequence the usb stick is the first
6. Tried to write the usb with BalenaEtcher, Ventoy, Rufus
7. Tried another usb stick too
8. Tried another usb port
9. Tried to install on another laptop (!!!) too!

So booting into grub is okay, but when I go to "Try or Install Ubuntu", or "Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)", or "OEM Install (for manufacturers)", in every case I get a big message saying this:

```
0.463350 - Initramfs unpacking failed: ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt

0.605267 - Failed to execute /init (error -2)

0.605355 - Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found. Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.

0.605398 - CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 not tainted 5.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu

0.605422 - Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 5558/086DKN, BIOS A18 12/30/2019

0.605444 - Call Trace:

0.605454 - <TASK>

0.605463 - show_stack+0x52/0x58

0.605478 - dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x5f

0.605493 - dump_stack+0x10/0x12

0.605506 - panic+0x149/0x321

0.605519 - ? putname+0x55/0x60

0.605533 - kernel_init+0x14c/0x150

0.605547 - ? rest_init+0x100/0x100

0.605560 - ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30

0.605575 - </TASK>

0.605608 - Kernel Offset: 0xcc00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)

0.605642 - ---( end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found. Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.[/CODE]
```

Could someone tell me the solution for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Data corruption suggests there is a problem either with the ISO or the USB. So, try another USB stick.

Comment: First re download the ISO. Next verify the ISO is good. Next remake the boot USB and last try again. See this site https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview The errors suggest the USB info is bad.

Comment: @David
That's why I started with the list. Second and third point. I already tried to download the ISO from all mirrors, on different computers and different places (with more stable internet connection), and the checksum was always right too.
Also tried the installation with other USB sticks, and on other computers.
But none of these tries helped.